# Magento 1.8 Emails not sending on production site

Tags: magento-1.8, email

We have a dev site and a live site on the one server. Emails such as `Email a friend`, `forgotten password`, `welcome emails` etc - they are sent on the development site but not on the live production site.

We have AOE Scheduler installed on both. `Cron` appears to be working fine. All extensions etc are the same on both sites, and as far as we can see any code changes are the same also. The mail settings in `System -> Config -> Advanced` are all the same.

Don't seem to be getting any relevant errors in the logs.

Is there anything we could try? The only thing that has just occurred to me in writing this is that the live site has `SSL` - is there any way this could be causing an issue?

Thanks for any pointers

Answer (score 0):

Ok - just in case anyone ever has a similar issue. Turns out this was because of the MailChimp/Mandrill extension. We weren't using Mandrill so had no API key in there, (or possibly an incorrect one) - once we looked in the Mandrill.log and found it had errors in it was just a matter of disabling Mandrill and then everything worked ok.